# Flask's built-in server is not blocking?

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

On many sites, including Stack Overflow, people say that Flask's built-in server (started by `app.run()`) only serves requests serially. Many say that if a handler takes a few seconds to respond, then the server would not be able to serve other requests in the meantime. Why am I seeing a totally opposite behavior with Flask 1.0.3?

```
@app.route('/slow')
def slow():
    time.sleep(5)
    return 'slow'


@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return 'hello'


app.run()
```

While the `slow` handler is sleeping, I can successfully fire off requests and receive responses for `hello`. Why is that? Can the development server handle multiple requests at a time then? I so, what part of Flask enables that?

Comment: What if you try triggering the `slow` handler successively? Just curious.

Comment: They also seem to run concurrently. If I hit `slow`, then hit it from another client 2 seconds after, then the second call would return 3 seconds after the first one, assuming each call takes 5 seconds.

Comment: sleep releases the GIL as mentioned [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue23251).) that could be a possible reason

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try with a blocking lock, like this:

```py
release = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=5)
while datetime.now() < release:
  continue
return 'slow'
```

`sleep` can be non-blocking, this just keeps it busy, the same way a heavy calculation would.